# Visual Studio 2015 Collapse all shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2015

[image: Solution explorer]

I have gone thru http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/ this link and Keyboard shortcuts inside Visual Studio to see if I can set up keyboard shortcut for "Collapse All" inside solution explorer so far no luck.
[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

FWIW I don't have access to Resharper and I did use CodeMaid for "Collapse all"

[image: Collapse all]

but after installing it every time I try to close my Visual Studio I ended with [error](https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid/issues/84) (tried suggestions from the [Github issue](https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid/issues/84) page but didn't work) so had to finally uninstall it

I have also referred many links like below ones but none of them helped.

- [Attach a keyboard shortcut to 'Collapse All' items in solution explorer with Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568114/attach-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-collapse-all-items-in-solution-explorer-with-vis)
- [Visual Studio: Is there a way to collapse all items of Solution Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357731/visual-studio-is-there-a-way-to-collapse-all-items-of-solution-explorer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you want to map is `SolutionExplorer.CollapseAll`.  The trick is that it won't work unless the Solution Explorer has focus, so you'll have to first use a keystroke to set focus (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+L) then your secondary keystroke you define.  The escape key afterwards will return focus to your previous window (e.g. code editor).

If you're still having any issues with CodeMaid, I would love to work them out with you.  The issues previously listed were for VS2013 and were difficult to consistently reproduce.

Comment: Thanks `SolutionExplorer.CollapseAll` did the trick (once the focus was set on SolutionExplorer)